# FFmpeg: How to control console output while reading from RTSP?

Tags: c++, c, boost, ffmpeg

So I created simple Consol app: FFmpeg RTSP Video stream reader (using only general FFmpeg C API) But while ffmpeg reads from RTSP it shows lots of info. I did not asked for if... At least not all of it... So how can I filter what ffmpeg is outputing? I mean in all he talls user-developer there is only one important line something like: `missing picture in acsess unit` so how to put some filter mechanism for ffmpeg not to output all it wants and for me developer to catch the moment when message I want appeares? (In my project I write in C++ under visual studio using Boost libs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use av_log_set_callback, to set your function as callback:

```
static void avlog_cb(void *, int level, const char * szFmt, va_list varg) {
    //do nothing...
}

av_log_set_callback(avlog_cb);
```

or, you may also use

```
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_ERROR);
```

to print error messages only.

Comment: Does it affect generated log when reading frames using OpenCV?